# Functional Equation Using Calculus

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, contest-math, functional-equations

I'm trying to solve this question using calculus, however am getting the incorrect answer. Can someone please point out my mistake.

Question: $$f(x)f(y) = f(x+y) + xy$$

My (incorrect) solution:
$$f'(x) = \lim \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim \frac{f(x)f(h) - xh - f(x)}{h}$$
$$f'(x) = \lim [-x + f(x) ( \frac{f(h) - 1}{h})]$$
$$f'(x) = -x + f(x)(\lim\frac{f(h)-1}{h})$$
Assuming the limit converges,
$$f'(x) = -x + kf(x)$$
I then solved this differential equation to get,
$$f(x) = A + 1/k^2 + x/k$$
The correct answers are $$f(x) = 1 - x$$ or $$f(x) = 1 + x$$ which were obtained via more standard methods for solving these questions.
However I cannot get the correct coefficents for my answer.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: There should be more conditions on your function: is it continuous, what are its initial values at say, $0$, is it differentiable? I doubt that functional equation on its own is sufficient

Comment: Your solution is wrong or incomplete, the homogeneous solution is $e^{kx}$, so that the general solution has the form $f(x)=Ae^{kx}+Bx+C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ and $k$ are not arbitrary. You know (both from the assumption about the limit, and from inspection of the functional equation) that $f(0) = 1$. Therefore, $A + 1/k^2 = 1$, so $f(x) = 1 + x/k$.

Now, plug this back into the functional equation

$$(1 + x/k)(1 + y/k) = 1 + (x+y)/k + xy)$$
$$1 + (x+y)/k + xy/k^2 = 1 + (x+y)/k + xy$$
$$xy/k^2 = xy$$

to observe that $k = \pm 1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I completely forgot I worked out f(0) = 1